# Copy pasting a special character in Latex

Tags: xetex

How do i copy past the pi character "&#960" from this link https://www.pisymbol.net/ into latex? Clearly copy pasting the character and giving the command

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\renewcommand{\pi}{\text{π}}
\begin{document}
$\pi$
\end{document}
```

Doest seem to work.

Comment: (pdf)LaTeX does not support Unicode text by default. Either you'll need a package or using (Xe/Lua)LaTeX

Comment: @JairoA.delRio Sure, how do I do with xeLatex? Could you please help me with the commands? Thank you.

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to achieve. What is wrong with the default definition of \pi? Why do you want to use a text pi instead inside math?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I like the pi font provided at the pisymbol.net page. Hence I am asking.

Comment: then you will need at first the font and will have to make it available to pdflatex or lualatex depending which engine you use. Neither engine can pull in some arbitrary glyph from a font sitting somewhere on the internet.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer : Thanks for the input. Not worth trying then :). Thanks, once again.

Comment: well you can see the symbol in your browser, so the font is perhaps not so far away. Use the tools of your browser to inspect the element and identify the font. On my system it seems to use Times New Roman.

Comment: the font is unrelated to the input syntax if you specify the font you want then you could use π or `\pi` or both to access that,

Comment: @crskhr is this question answered?